# set of all trace $1$ matrices are connected?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

The heading is the question and here are my two approach, I want to know are they correct or not, if not I need to know the answer:

1) They are path connected as $\gamma(t)=At+(1-t)B, t\in [0,1]$  where $A$ and $B$ are trace one matrices. But I am not sure all matrices in this path are trace $1$?

2) as trace equals $1$, so considering diagonal entries I get a hyperplane $H$ with $x_{11}+\dots+x_{nn}=1$ and remaining other $n^2-n$ entries I can send to $\mathbb{R}^{n^2-n}$ and thus they are homeomorphic to $H\times \mathbb{R}^{n^2-n}$ as this is a product of two connected topological spaces, it is connected. So trace 1 matrices are connected. Well, here I have considered a matrix is just a point in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$

Thank you.

Comment: For 1) Isn't the trace linear? $\text{tr} \gamma(t)=t\cdot\text{tr}(A)+(1-t)\cdot\text{tr}B=t+(1-t)=1, \forall t$

Comment: If you are not requiring that all matrices are invertible, then as your (2) points out, the trace 1 matrices is a hyperplane in $k^{n^2}$, hence homeomorphic to $k^{n^2-1}$, and hence connected. Here $k=\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Partial answer for 1)  $\text{tr} (\gamma(t))=t\cdot\text{tr}(A)+(1-t)\cdot\text{tr}(B)=t+(1-t)=1, \forall t$